# Angular 6: Get Token from localStorage After Refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, jwt, local-storage

**EDIT: I update the code with the answer that PierreDuc gave me. He's solution works for me. I edit the code so everyone could see the working code**

I'm using canActivate and canActivateChild to know if someone have token for my web and I want to block anyone who don't have token already.
I'm using localStorage for the user data and token.

When I try to login with user id:1, the guard navigate to page not found, but after I refresh the page I gain access to the page.
When I used debugger I saw that before I refreshed the localStorage was empty but had values after the refresh.

Why this is happening? how can I fix it?
This is the relevant code:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login/:id', canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [] },
  { path: '', canActivateChild: [AuthGuard], children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/courses', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'courses', component: CourseListComponent,  pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'courses/:courseId', component: CourseDetailComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'courses/:courseId/unit/:unitId', component: CoursePlayComponent,
      children: [
        { path: '', component: CourseListComponent },
        { path: 'lesson/:lessonId', component: CourseLessonComponent, data:{ type: 'lesson'} },
        { path: 'quiz/:quizId', component: CourseQuizComponent, data: {type: 'quiz'} }
      ]}
    ]},
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }];
```

**auth.guard.ts**

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate , CanActivateChild {

    constructor(private authUserService: AuthUserService, private router: Router) {   }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:
    RouterStateSnapshot): boolean |
    Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
      // save the id from route snapshot
      const id = +route.params.id;

      // if you try to logging with id
      if (id) {
        this.router.navigate(["/courses"]);
        return this.authUserService.login(id);
      }

      // if you already logged and just navigate between pages
      else if (this.authUserService.isLoggedIn())
         return true;

      else {
        this.router.navigate(["/page_not_found"]);
        return false;
      }
     }

      canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean |
      Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
         return this.canActivate(route, state);
       }

}
```

**auth-user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable , BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { LocalStorage } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { catchError, groupBy } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { IUser } from './user';

@Injectable()
export class AuthUserService implements OnDestroy {

  private user: IUser;
  private errorMessage: string;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  // store the session and call http get
  login(id: number) {
    return this.userService.getUser(id).pipe(
      map((user) => {
        this.user = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user));
        localStorage.setItem('token', 'JWT');
        return true;
      }),
      catchError((error) => {
        this.errorMessage = <any>error;
        return of(false);
      })
    );
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
   return !!localStorage.getItem('token');
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `userService.getUser` is async, it won't be finished and will set your localStorage after you already checked it.

Change your authService to this:

```
login(id: number) {
  return this.userService.getUser(id).pipe(
    map((user) => {
      this.user = user;
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user));
      localStorage.setItem('token', 'JWT');
      return true;
    }),
    catchError((error) => {
      this.errorMessage = <any>error;
      return of(false);
    })
  );
}
```

And update your guard to this:

```
if (id) {
  this.router.navigate(["/courses"]);
  return this.authUserService.login(id);
}
```

Comment: I did as you said and now I get this error when I try to go for localhost:4200/login/1 => ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: of is not defined

Comment: I tried to change it for return false and now I get an empty page and the route is empty route and I don't see any data. I'll add that I display data from the localStorage on the page /courses

Comment: of is a operator from rxjs, you have to import it using `import { of } from 'rxjs';` Same for the `catchError` and the `map`. CatchError has to return an observable

Comment: did you add the `return true` to the authService? And can you check if it enters the  catchError or not. Because if that observable returns true, it should automatically navigate

Comment: now I added a console.log and I got false drom login id, but when I refresh the page I get all the data so it's still the same. I'll edit the code in the post for you to see my changes

Comment: but you didn't apply my changes at all. You still have a `subscribe` in your login method. You still are not returning the observable from the method. And you are still navigating inside the guard for some reason. The `if (id) {` should just be that one line. This returns the observable which is resolved inside the angular when checking the guard

Comment: oh I didn't noticed you changed it to map. What's the different between map and subscribe?

Comment: map updates the value emitted by the observable. Subscribe triggers the cold observable.. Which is not what you want there, but only when angular checks the guard

Comment: I changed it now to map and I got this error: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: map is not defined

Comment: yes, you have to import that as well like i said :D `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: I imported but not from rxjs/operators but from rxjs. I changed it and now I have this error: core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Comment: Yes.. you have to import it from `rxjs/operators`

Comment: I edited the code and fixed the error I got. I added console.log in login function and I saw that I indeed get the user now but nothing is present me in the page, and the route is still login/1 and not /courses. if I do refresh all the data works and I see it

Comment: ah yes, I misread your routes. You use the same guard for your login/:id path as well. You have to add the redirect then indeed. Sorry about that.  I'll update my answer

Comment: Hi, I just found this page. My question is that I have a login page in login component. But when I route to another page, how can I know if I am logged in? How to retrieve the token and compare it?